# What bracha should one make on a chicken pot pie?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, mezonot-beracha

What bracha should one make on a chicken pot pie?

Choices that could make sense:

Shehakol: Because chicken is the  main thing or if one is uncertain.

Mezonot:  Because it is a pie crust made using wheat flour.

Shehahol and Mezonot: Because both items are of equal importance (I believe this is the standard opinion for spaghetti and meatballs).

Just to complicate matters, chicken pot pies often have "Ha-Adamah" root vegetables like carrots or potatoes or green vegetables like peas.  Since they are of secondary importance, I do not know if it would affect anything or not.

Comment: Perhaps HaMotzi like pizza?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86698/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is: Mezonos because the crust is not insignificant and is chameshes minei dagan. http://revach.net/lists/index.php?bera=1&search=Chicken%20%20Pie&id=151

Comment: [Further source for R' Bodner's *p'sak*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6rz4tkdzkmsC&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Why is it not HaMotzi?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you're kovea seudah on apple pie, you'd make a hamotzi too, so I don't see why chicken pot pie should be any worse. (Which is to say, I hear your point, and the *standard* brocho perhaps should be hamotzi if one is most often kovea seudah on it anyway and eats the equivalent of a kzayis of flour...)

Comment: "if one is most often kovea seudah on it anyway and eats the equivalent of a kzayis of flour." That seems to describe chicken pot pie perfectly. It's not a snack food at all. Thus, it's clearly Hamotzi.