# What is the bracha for a deli roll?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, meat, bread

A deli roll is a puff pastry dough rubbed with mustard and filled with assorted deli meats (usually pastrami and turkey.)

Is this considered *pas haba bekisnin*? (one definition of this term is:

> רבנו חננאל, מסכת ברכות דף מב. ואמר כיון שהזכיר רב ששת פת הבא בכיסנין,
>   פירש זו הפת העשויה כמין כיסין מלאים סוכר ושקדים ואגוזים וכיוצא בהן…
>   Rabbenu Hanan’el, Commentary to Masekhet Berakhot 42a And it says that
>   when Rav Sheshet mentions pat haba bekisnin, he explains this as bread
>   that is made like a type of pocket that is filled with sugar, almonds,
>   walnuts, etc…

The above definition sounds like a pastry or "turnover". However, it defines filling with sweet items or nuts.

I'm not sure if this definition would be applied to a deli roll which seems to be shaped similarly (i.e., it is a "filled" dough.)

There is also a generally accepted rule among most current *poskim* stating that regardless of the shape / form, if the food is normally eaten as a meal and not a snack, one would have to wash and say "hamotzi", anyway. I'm not sure what the status of a deli roll is.

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/862472/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-the-proper-beracha-on-deli-roll/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this answer from [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2010/11/07/deli-roll/) (excerpts) covers all the angles of the multiple definitions of pat haba bekisnin as it applies to deli roll:

> Poskim dispute whether or not a meat filling renders a food pas haba
>   bekisnin. However, I understand that the deli roll is usually eaten as
>   an appetizer, or snack. Assuming this is the case, all would concur
>   that it has the status of pas haba bekisnin.  It is true that the
>   principle of filled pastry applies first and foremost to sweet
>   fillings. According to Taz (168:6), it applies even to fillings of
>   meat, whereas Magen Avraham (168:16) writes that a meat filling would
>   not change the berachah from hamotzi to mezonos–which is the opinion
>   quoted by Mishnah Berurah (168:94). However, Chayei Adam (54:5) rules
>   that bedieved one can rely on the Taz, and recite mezonos on a
>   meat-filled pastry. This would be difficult to rely on, in view of the
>   Magen Avraham and Mishnah Berurah (and Shulchan Aruch Harav). But, to
>   my knowledge, the case of the deli roll is somewhat different, because
>   it is classically served as a snack/appetizer, and not as a main
>   course or a meal. Assuming this to be true, all would agree that its
>   filling renders it pas haba bekisnin, just as in the case of sweet
>   fillings. In addition, some maintain that puff pastry is considered
>   thin/crispy and qualifies to be pas haba bekisnin (this is the opinion
>   of Yalkut Yosef), though not all agree to this. If the pastry is
>   kneaded with a maojrity part of fat/margarine (minus the water
>   content) it would also be sufficient to consider it pas haba bekisnin.

---

**Supplemental Note** (Nissan 24, 5779): I infer from the above analysis, that a knish (any kind) would also be considered *pat haba bekisnin*.